# Any suggestions on learning Data structures and algorithms for java developers

Tags: java, algorithm

What algorithms should a java developer(or maybe a better question would be a software developer in general) should know. I have Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen and Algorithms by Richard Johnsonbaugh at hand. Would going through  their content be overkill?

Answer (score 1):

from amazon [data structures and algorithms in java](http://amzn.to/gegrGw)

> What algorithms should a java developer(or maybe a better question would be a software developer in general) should know.

There are no any specific Algorithms for C developers or for a Java developer. Algorithms is a "main" part of the Computer Science and here is the topic [What algorithms should every developer know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445425/what-algorithms-should-every-developer-know) and here [Best source for Algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71029/best-source-for-algorithms) and [Good Data Structures text book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366317/good-data-structures-text-book)

Comment: There is a difference in the kinds of algorithms you use in imperative languages and the kinds you use in functional languages, so while there's no "algorithms for C/Java/whatever developers" you do have to distinguish, often, by the governing paradigm.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. what I mean is briefly "pseudocode". It is not the "language-depended", it is algorithm. Of course, I know the difference of "the kinds of algorithms you use in imperative languages and the kinds you use in functional languages"

Answer (score 1):

That's a very open-ended question, so a concise and useful answer is difficult.  I would say that you need to know at least the data-structures and associated algorithms that Java provides in the standard libraries so that you know how and when to use each one.  If you don't know the differences in structure and performance between an ArrayList and a LinkedList then you won't know when each one is appropriate.  Similarly, if you don't know how a HashMap works then you can't know how to properly define classes that can be stored in one.

It's also instructive to learn a couple of different sorting and searching algorithms, for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445425/what-algorithms-should-every-developer-know) better answers what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't hurt to know stuff like that, but it will rarely come up*.

*Depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The CLRS is probably the most widely used one and reading it is definitely not overkill, just skip the proofs (I would read them just to enjoy, but not too much practical use).  You may also want to check [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948600).